# About predictions while using lrm() function

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, ordinal

I have maybe stupid question, but still...

Trying to learn something about logistic regression and found this article [Logistic Models in R](http://newton.uor.edu/facultyfolder/jim_bentley/Downloads/R/LogisticRegUsingLRM.pdf)

In this case it is fully understandable that the higher value of Y axis then the higher chances to survive, but what if there more than 2 answers in "Survived"?

So the question is: what if "Survived" factor could have 3 or more answers, what Predictions could we make by looking at plots?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then you need a related type of model called a [multinomial logistic regression model](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm).

Comment: Thanks, man! I'll try to figure something out.